# How do I determine the subsidence of land in Manila, Jakarta and Bangkok?

Tags: dem, elevation

Can I see how these cities have lost elevation using digital elevation models? Is there a digital elevation model which data are updated? Or are there other methods?

Comment: Do you mean comparing two DEMs from different times to see how elevation has changed?  Also what software are you using?

Comment: Yea. And i use ArcGis 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're asking, you want to see what has changed between two DEMs from two seperate time periods.  Assuming that these two datasets have the same resolution you would want to use the [minus](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z00000093000000.htm) tool (you need to have spatial analysis licensed) and that will give you the difference between the pixels in each data set.  So if one pixel has a value 1454m at one data and the corresponding pixel from a later date with an elevation of 1450m a raster would be created that has a pixel value of -4m.

Comment: I have a license spatial analysis. Where can I take the DEM is from a different time? And thanks you:)

Comment: You can create them from LiDAR or stereo-pairs flown at two seperate times, or there may already be DEMs created.  As to whether this exists for these specific locations you would need to do some looking.  Asking for specific datasets like that here won't yeild much unless they are widely used.

Comment: I use this method and i get output raster high 134 low - 134. What is wrong?

Comment: You would need to post the datasets used to have that answered, but it could be a result of the rasters having different extents.